# Ruby/Rails Audio Conversion Plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, audio

I am looking for a good gem/plugin to convert user-uploaded audio files to different formats.  One format in particular that I am interested in is converting to Apple .caf with ima4 compression for inclusion in an iPhone app.

I have been using afconvert on my mac for this so far, but I need to do it on my linux box, server-side.  Ideally, I would be able to work into paperclip.

As an additional solution, ffmpeg could work, but I have not seen any .caf options for it.  Anybody know of one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Sound eXchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) project supports lots of audio file conversions.  I've used this in the past to convert aiff files output by the OS X "say" program to ulaw files for Asterisk.  This yields rather nice text-to-speech.  For my purposes, I also found a Ruby extension on github called [sox-ruby](http://github.com/Beirdo/sox-ruby/) that wraps the libsox functions directly.